# What version of scalatest to use with Akka 2.5.11?

Tags: java, scala, junit, akka

I am trying to write a test following this documentation:

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/fsm.html#overview

This looks like to extend the AbstractJavaTest I need the scalatest dependency so I added the following to my `pom`:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

From more googling I found that this class only extends the JUnitSuite, I am able to import it in my class, but I cant seen to extend it

THis works

```
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitSuite;
```

But this doesn't

```
public class MyTest extends JunitSuite {}
```

How do I get the JunitSuite class?

Comment: Why are you trying to use the latest version of Akka with an antedeluvian scalatest version from 2010? What is "JunitSuite"? Did you try it with `JUnitSuite` instead? Looks like trivial typo so far.

Comment: that was embarassing, thanks!

Comment: @user_mda Does the question still make any sense? If not, just delete it. It's embarassing to me too now, because I made a typo in "antediluvian"^^ -_-

Comment: I had too google it , it made sense to google

Comment: I can't modify my comment any more, I've at least typed it correctly in the answer... xD

Answer (score 0):

You picked a truly antediluvian version of ScalaTest from 2010, whereas your Akka version is very recent.

Just go to [Maven Central, scalatest](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest/scalatest) and pick some newer version, you could try for example

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
  <artifactId>scalatest_2.12</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0-SNAP10</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Just make sure that you use either `2.11` or `2.12` consistently.